when does $m(A/E)=m(A)-m(E)$?
I have to show that $E \in M \iff m(A/E)<\epsilon$
$\forall$ A open set $\supset$ E
for $\leftarrow$  is ok
the other direction I know that $m(E)=inf_{A \supset E , \text{A open} }m(A)$ so $\exists A_\epsilon$ such that  $m(A_\epsilon)\leq m(E) + \epsilon$
so for misurability I have $m(A_{\epsilon}/E)<\epsilon$
I know that if the sets are measurable and $A  \supset E$ I have Caratheodor conditions that tells me $m(A)=m(E)+m(A/E)$ but I don't know if I can riarrange and write $m(A)-m(E)=m(A/E)$
because if I have $\infty-\infty$?
but $m(A)=m(E)+m(A/E)$ is right because  $\infty=\infty+ \text{something positive}$
So my question is does $m(E)$ be finite to apply Caratheory ?

What is $M$ and $m$?

By $A/E$, do you mean set difference $A \setminus E = {x \in A \mid x \notin E}$? Also, the thing you are trying to prove doesn’t make sense to me. Is it maybe $E \text{ is measurable} \iff \forall \varepsilon > 0\ \exists \text{open } A \supseteq E \text{ s.t. } m(A \setminus E) < \varepsilon$?

@X-Rui yes sorry

@DanielP M measurable set , m measure

(I'll assume with m(E) you mean $\mathscr{L}^n(E)$ the Lebesgue-measure and E $\subseteq$ $R^n$)
You're right. If we have m(E)= $\infty$ we can't just say m(A\E) = m(A) - m(E) < $\epsilon$.
We have to set $E_k$ = $E\cap[-k,k]^n$ for k $\in$ $\mathbf N$ with $E = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{i}$ .
Now, for every k  choose $A_k$ open such that $E_k$ $\subseteq$ $A_k$ with $m(A_k\setminus E_k)= m(A_k) - m(E_k) < \frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$, using $m(E_k)=inf_{A_k \supset E_k}m(A_k)$ and Caratheodory's criterion.
Then A = $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}$ is open, E $\subseteq$ A, and $m(A \setminus E) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} m(A_k \setminus E_k) < \varepsilon$ because $A \setminus E = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} (A_k \setminus E) \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} (A_k \setminus E_k)$ and the sub-additivity of the measure and we're done.
